# Could not install json.Error occurs in windows.ERROR: Error installing json:ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: json, ruby, rubygems

While trying to install Json -v 1.8.5 I am getting the below error.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Ruby version:ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x64-mingw32]

Gem version:2.6.8

```
 C:\Users\apzal.bahin\Documents\Business Media\Learning\Cucumber calabash\Calabas
    hCucumberTest>gem install json -v 1.8.5
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing json:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.5/ext/jso
    n/ext/generator
    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170113-12584-dvx97z.rb extconf.rb
    creating Makefile

    current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.5/ext/json/ex
    t/generator
    make "DESTDIR=" clean

    current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.5/ext/json/ex
    t/generator
    make "DESTDIR="
    generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
    compiling generator.c
    make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found
    make: *** [generator.o] Error 127

    make failed, exit code 2

    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1
    .8.5 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0
    /json-1.8.5/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Make sure devkit installed correctly and verify by looking at config.yml in your devkit dir.

Comment: My ruby path is already added to devkit `- C:/Ruby22-x64`. and I ran both the comments ruby `dk.rb init ruby` and  `dk.rb install`.Any other possible route cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re installed ruby and devkit ,now its working fine.Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If your are not is proxy then use below code:

**`"gem install <gemname> -v <version no> --platform=ruby --verbose"`**

Else if you were in proxy

**`"gem install <gemname> -v <version no> --platform=ruby --verbose --http-proxy http://<username:password>@<proxyserver address>"`**

Comment: I am getting this error.                                                                           ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError)
    Illformed requirement ["--platform=ruby"]

Comment: Again I am getting the same error .I tried this                                                                            `gem install json -v 1.8.5 --platform=ruby --verbose`                         `ERROR:  Error installing json:`
`ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`...I have the same error in the question I posted